# Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1
>   Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jignesh.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Did you refactor any `xml` files recently?

Comment: no its new project & I just update android studio and install 7.0 and 7.0.1  @Gidi Sprintzin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all SDK and SDK TOOL from SDK manager and reinstall

Answer (score 2):

You have to use maven repository too in your project gradle file -

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And sync your project, it will work :-)

Answer (score 1):

In android studio, tools->android->sdk manager->sdk tools->
update a android support repository rev 41.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved on commenting some lines in gradle

```
dependencies {

//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.alert_dialog.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {

//    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

//    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't understand why this is not automatically catered for when you create a new project...
Solution is to add

```
 maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
```

under allprojects => repositories in project level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

The Espresso version you are using is outdated. You need to add the following version -

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

Please check their documentation - [Espresso Docs](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to your `build.gradle`.

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Another Approach to solve this.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: one error solved by you solution but second Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1   @jaydroider

Comment: @user2599329 Check my updated answer and apply that.

Comment: this error dose not resolved with upated answer Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1  @jaydroider

Comment: @user2599329 May be downgrade version for *appcompat*  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'`. And try to clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings-> Android SDK

Download all the required platforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

and it would solve the problem but I don't think its the most efficient way because when you do this you'll probably be getting rendering errors or warning on your activity.xml page and you don't want to risk that.

another way to solve this is to go to

tools ==> appearance and behavior ==> system settings ==> android SDK ==> SDK platforms and untick all android versions listed above android 7.0(Nougat).

close android studio and restart your project.

I use android 2.2 and have not upgraded to the latest so this solution might be different and not work on other android studio versions.

I hope this helps.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

See In your SDK tools which SKD you already Downloaded.
And choice one of them like 21.3.4 ...
note: must get below of buildToolsVersion and compiler your project.

Answer (score -2):

dependencies {

//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Comment: Welcome to SO :) and seasons greetings! Thank-you for contributing. If you get a chance could you possibly check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer so that you can optimise your rep building skillz.