# Android Studio Gradle Project Sync - Failed To Resolve Espresso-Core and Appcompat

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am following the 'First App' tutorial found at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html.
However, on creating a default 'Empty activity' project and trying to build it, I receive the following errors:

> - Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:espresso-core:2.2.2
> - Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+

My (default / autogenerated) build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Although I have looked at several related Stack Overflow questions, I am yet to find a solution that works. I am using a fresh, default install of Android Studio 2.3.3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your time, I have since fixed the problem!

Although I am unsure as to what caused it, completely deleting and reinstalling Android Studio and the Java SDK has made the errors go away. I believe it may have been conflicting with some android software I installed a long time ago!

Thanks again for your suggestions, Oli

Comment: What Android Studio version are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You should check if your `repository` includes new google maven repo.
Something like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Used `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the dependancy to this

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Using + might cause unstable builds.

Goto SDK Manager and Download/Update all required tools and platforms.
That should solve the error.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work, as the version currently being used is 7:26, not 7:25, I still get the same errors.

Comment: There is no stable build for version 26 as of now, try `26.0.0-beta1`

Comment: Sorry, still not working. Is Espresso needed, or is there a way of removing it? I just want a very simple test app.

Comment: [Try this link, its the same error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884845/error26-13-failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v725-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in new gradle 4.1

instead of compile we should use **implementation** in build.gradle file

```
*implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'*
```

gradle class path is

```
*classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8'*
```